# How to identify edge number from node path in a phylogeny?

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I'm trying to identify edge numbers delimited by pairs of nodes in a **phylogenetic** tree. For example, say that internal branch **1** is bound by nodes **22** and **23**. Of course, that can be visually done with `nodelabels()` and `edgelabels()`, but I'm working with a phylogeny with thousands of tips and hence need an automated way.

Is there any command to match node numbers with edge numbers?

Comment: Look at the `mrca` and `getMRCA` functions from the `ape` package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the edge table stored in the `phylo` object as `$edge`:

```
## A random tree
tree <- rtree(5)
tree$edge
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    6    7
#[2,]    7    1
#[3,]    7    2
#[4,]    6    8
#[5,]    8    3
#[6,]    8    9
#[7,]    9    4
#[8,]    9    5
```

The way to read these tables is: the row numbers are the edge numbers (what you're after), the first column is the parent node and the second column is the child tip/node:

```
## The edge table
edge_table <- tree$edge
rownames(edge_table) <- paste("edge", 1:nrow(edge_table), sep = ""))
colnames(edge_table) <- c("parent", "child")
edge_table
#      parent child
#edge1      6     7
#edge2      7     1
#edge3      7     2
#edge4      6     8
#edge5      8     3
#edge6      8     9
#edge7      9     4
#edge8      9     5
```

Nodes/tips 1 to 5 (`Ntip(tree)`) are tips and then, 6 is the first node (e.g. root) up to `Ntip(tree) + Nnode(tree)`.

To select any edges based on nodes, you can run the following:

```
## Getting the nodes of interest
nodes_of_interest <- c(6, 7, 8)

## Getting the edges connecting to the nodes
edge_parent <- rownames(edge_table)[edge_table[,1] %in% nodes_of_interest]
edge_child  <- rownames(edge_table)[edge_table[,2] %in% nodes_of_interest]
```

This is of course generalisable to any tree size (e.g. 8000+) since all the edge attributions are automatic.

Comment: Hi Thomas,Sorry for the long delay here, and thanks for answering! But what I'm really looking for is a sort of automated way to do it. I'm working on a tree with 8,000+ tips so looking at it manually would be quite daunting. Do you know if there's a function that will take a list of nodes and output the respective edges delimited by those nodes? 

Say I have nodes: "9148 9149 9151 9155 9157 9158 9159 9164 9167 9168 9169 9172 9174 9178 9179 9183 9184 9186 9188 58"

Can I obtain a corresponding list of edges somehow?

Comment: I don't see why that would be a problem. I've updated the post to illustrate how to do it with this small example tree but you can totally attribute any node number to `nodes_of_interest`.

Comment: Oh, this is great! I think it worked fine. One last dumb question while we're at it: is that a function to color only specific edges (say, edges 12, 32, 51) of a phylogeny in a given color? The way I know how to do it is through the edge.color argument, but to do that I'd have to build a variable with color names for every single branch of the phylogeny (over 9,000 in my case). I'm pretty sure there's gotta be an easier way to do it, but things like plotBranchbyTrait or paintBranches won't work for that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use `match` to get a logical vector for two colors (say `my_colors <- c("orange", "blue")`) for the edges of interest (say `my_edges <- c(12, 32, 51)`) as follows `my_colors[as.numeric(is.na(match(1:Nedge(tree), my_edges)))+1]`.