# Labelling internal nodes in phylogeny based on string present in tip labels with R

Tags: r, phylogeny

I am working with a set of phylogenies where some of the tips, corresponding to species of interest, are labelled `{Foreground}`. I produced those labelled phylogenies using [this code](https://github.com/mbarkdull/FormicidaeMolecularEvolution/blob/main/scripts/LabellingPhylogeniesHYPHY.R), in case that's useful. For example:

```
((dqua_filteredTranscripts_dqua_XP_014485378_1_p1{Foreground}:0.16707,(hsal_filteredTranscripts_hsal_XP_019699576_1_p1{Foreground}:0.09303,obru_filteredTranscripts_obru_XP_032675222_1{Foreground}:0.14764)n2:0.0264)n1:0.081515,(lhum_filteredTranscripts_lhum_XP_012225643_1:0.15063,((((lnig_filteredTranscripts_lnig_lcl|LBMM01007291_1_cds_KMQ89872_1_9717_p1:0.03303,nful_filteredTranscripts_nful_XP_029159864_1:0.06193)n7:0.0208,(fexs_filteredTranscripts_fexs_XP_029666948_1_p1:0.05165,cflo_filteredTranscripts_cflo_XP_011252390_1:0.14872)n8:0.01846)n6:0.09014,((ebur_filteredTranscripts_ebur_evm_model_scaffold_4_137_p1:0.16113,obir_filteredTranscripts_obir_XP_011352658_1:0.18685)n10:0.16551,pgra_filteredTranscripts_pgra_XP_020292968_1:0.26079)n9:0.02221)n5:0.01985,(pbar_filteredTranscripts_pbar_XP_011642439_1:0.14069,((mpha_filteredTranscripts_mpha_XP_028047735_2:0.22823,((tcur_filteredTranscripts_tcur_XP_024882433_1:0.00706,tcur_filteredTranscripts_tcur_XP_024887856_1:0.00054)n15:0.08977,(cobs_filteredTranscripts_cobs_Cobs_17518mRNA1_p1:0.18228,veme_filteredTranscripts_veme_XP_011868525_1_p1:0.18631)n16:0.02472)n14:0.04118)n13:0.01637,(((waur_filteredTranscripts_waur_XP_011691747_1:0.00055,waur_filteredTranscripts_waur_XP_011706608_1:0.00054)n19:0.14732,(ccos_filteredTranscripts_ccos_XP_018403444_1:0.05989,(tsep_filteredTranscripts_tsep_XP_018353851_1{Foreground}:0.03875,(acol_filteredTranscripts_acol_XP_018049575_1_p1{Foreground}:0.03578,aech_filteredTranscripts_aech_XP_011050323_1{Foreground}:0.03598)n22:0.00783)n21:0.03036)n20:0.05015)n18:0.0229,(cvar_filteredTranscripts_cvar_CVAR_10443RA_p1:0.09577,sinv_filteredTranscripts_sinv_XP_011164490_1:0.09784)n23:0.01294)n17:0.01659)n12:0.04417)n11:0.07617)n4:0.03295)n3:0.081515)n0;
```

[image]

I need to also add the label `{Foreground}` to the internal nodes parent to the labelled tips and NOT parent to any unlabelled tips, e.g. my desired result would be:

```
((dqua_filteredTranscripts_dqua_XP_014485378_1_p1{Foreground}:0.16707,(hsal_filteredTranscripts_hsal_XP_019699576_1_p1{Foreground}:0.09303,obru_filteredTranscripts_obru_XP_032675222_1{Foreground}:0.14764)n2{Foreground}:0.0264)n1{Foreground}:0.081515,(lhum_filteredTranscripts_lhum_XP_012225643_1:0.15063,((((lnig_filteredTranscripts_lnig_lcl|LBMM01007291_1_cds_KMQ89872_1_9717_p1:0.03303,nful_filteredTranscripts_nful_XP_029159864_1:0.06193)n7:0.0208,(fexs_filteredTranscripts_fexs_XP_029666948_1_p1:0.05165,cflo_filteredTranscripts_cflo_XP_011252390_1:0.14872)n8:0.01846)n6:0.09014,((ebur_filteredTranscripts_ebur_evm_model_scaffold_4_137_p1:0.16113,obir_filteredTranscripts_obir_XP_011352658_1:0.18685)n10:0.16551,pgra_filteredTranscripts_pgra_XP_020292968_1:0.26079)n9:0.02221)n5:0.01985,(pbar_filteredTranscripts_pbar_XP_011642439_1:0.14069,((mpha_filteredTranscripts_mpha_XP_028047735_2:0.22823,((tcur_filteredTranscripts_tcur_XP_024882433_1:0.00706,tcur_filteredTranscripts_tcur_XP_024887856_1:0.00054)n15:0.08977,(cobs_filteredTranscripts_cobs_Cobs_17518mRNA1_p1:0.18228,veme_filteredTranscripts_veme_XP_011868525_1_p1:0.18631)n16:0.02472)n14:0.04118)n13:0.01637,(((waur_filteredTranscripts_waur_XP_011691747_1:0.00055,waur_filteredTranscripts_waur_XP_011706608_1:0.00054)n19:0.14732,(ccos_filteredTranscripts_ccos_XP_018403444_1:0.05989,(tsep_filteredTranscripts_tsep_XP_018353851_1{Foreground}:0.03875,(acol_filteredTranscripts_acol_XP_018049575_1_p1{Foreground}:0.03578,aech_filteredTranscripts_aech_XP_011050323_1{Foreground}:0.03598)n22{Foreground}:0.00783)n21{Foreground}:0.03036)n20:0.05015)n18:0.0229,(cvar_filteredTranscripts_cvar_CVAR_10443RA_p1:0.09577,sinv_filteredTranscripts_sinv_XP_011164490_1:0.09784)n23:0.01294)n17:0.01659)n12:0.04417)n11:0.07617)n4:0.03295)n3:0.081515):0;
```

[image: Image of the previous Newick phylogeny]

I've tried using `ape::makeNodeLabel`, supplying a list of the species abbreviations for my labelled species:

```
ape::makeNodeLabel(test, method = "user", nodeList = list(`{Foreground}` = c("aech", "acol", "tsep", "obru", "hsal", "dqua")))
```

However, that method labels the node parent to *all* of my labelled tips and to unlabelled tips as well, e.g.:

```
((dqua_filteredTranscripts_dqua_XP_014485378_1_p1{Foreground}:0.16707,(hsal_filteredTranscripts_hsal_XP_019699576_1_p1{Foreground}:0.09303,obru_filteredTranscripts_obru_XP_032675222_1{Foreground}:0.14764)n2:0.0264)n1:0.081515,(lhum_filteredTranscripts_lhum_XP_012225643_1:0.15063,((((lnig_filteredTranscripts_lnig_lcl|LBMM01007291_1_cds_KMQ89872_1_9717_p1:0.03303,nful_filteredTranscripts_nful_XP_029159864_1:0.06193)n7:0.0208,(fexs_filteredTranscripts_fexs_XP_029666948_1_p1:0.05165,cflo_filteredTranscripts_cflo_XP_011252390_1:0.14872)n8:0.01846)n6:0.09014,((ebur_filteredTranscripts_ebur_evm_model_scaffold_4_137_p1:0.16113,obir_filteredTranscripts_obir_XP_011352658_1:0.18685)n10:0.16551,pgra_filteredTranscripts_pgra_XP_020292968_1:0.26079)n9:0.02221)n5:0.01985,(pbar_filteredTranscripts_pbar_XP_011642439_1:0.14069,((mpha_filteredTranscripts_mpha_XP_028047735_2:0.22823,((tcur_filteredTranscripts_tcur_XP_024882433_1:0.00706,tcur_filteredTranscripts_tcur_XP_024887856_1:0.00054)n15:0.08977,(cobs_filteredTranscripts_cobs_Cobs_17518mRNA1_p1:0.18228,veme_filteredTranscripts_veme_XP_011868525_1_p1:0.18631)n16:0.02472)n14:0.04118)n13:0.01637,(((waur_filteredTranscripts_waur_XP_011691747_1:0.00055,waur_filteredTranscripts_waur_XP_011706608_1:0.00054)n19:0.14732,(ccos_filteredTranscripts_ccos_XP_018403444_1:0.05989,(tsep_filteredTranscripts_tsep_XP_018353851_1{Foreground}:0.03875,(acol_filteredTranscripts_acol_XP_018049575_1_p1{Foreground}:0.03578,aech_filteredTranscripts_aech_XP_011050323_1{Foreground}:0.03598)n22:0.00783)n21:0.03036)n20:0.05015)n18:0.0229,(cvar_filteredTranscripts_cvar_CVAR_10443RA_p1:0.09577,sinv_filteredTranscripts_sinv_XP_011164490_1:0.09784)n23:0.01294)n17:0.01659)n12:0.04417)n11:0.07617)n4:0.03295)n3:0.081515){Foreground};
```

[image: graphic representation of the previous Newick formatted phylogeny]

Crucially, the phylogenies I need to manipulate can contain only a subset of the list of species of interest, and might contain multiple tips per species of interest (i.e. two tips containing the abbreviation `aech` in a single tree). I'll need to perform this labelling procedure on thousands of phylogenies containing different sets of species. I'd like to be able to supply a vector of species abbreviations (`c("aech", "acol", "tsep", "obru", "hsal", "dqua")`) and output the phylogeny I described above.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your data so I'm going to show a solution using a random tree:

```
## A random tree with node labels
tree <- rtree(50)
tree <- makeNodeLabel(tree)

## Attributing the term "{Foreground}" to 10 random tips
selected_tips <- sample(1:50, 10)
tree$tip.label[selected_tips] <- paste(tree$tip.label[selected_tips], "{Foreground}")
```

Step one is finding the tips that contain the term `{Foreground}` (or/and  `"aech"`, `"acol"`, etc. the logic is the same).

```
## Finding which tip has the term "{Foreground}" (assuming we did not generate it randomly before)
selected_tips <- grep("\\{Foreground\\}", tree$tip.label)
```

We can then find which nodes are the direct descendants of these tips (more on how to read [$edge tables here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55873364/how-to-identify-edge-number-from-node-path-in-a-phylogeny/56032170#56032170))

```
## Finding the direct ancestor for each of these tips
descendants <- tree$edge[tree$edge[, 2] %in% selected_tips, 1]
```

And then create a string of node labels that contains only these selected descendants

```
## Adding the term "{Foreground}" to the selected descendants (the -Ntip(tree) part is because the node counting in the $edge table starts at the value Ntip(tree)).
tree$node.label[descendants-Ntip(tree)] <- paste(tree$node.label[descendants-Ntip(tree)], "{Foreground}")
## Replacing all the non selected node labels by nothing ("")
tree$node.label[-c(descendants-Ntip(tree))] <- ""

## Plotting the results
plot(tree)
nodelabels(tree$node.label)
```